# WCF Passing AD Login from win client, then validating it is correct in WCF Server

Tags: wcf, single-sign-on

I am wanting to create an application in winforms that calls a new WCF application that I create, and I want it to pass the current windows login credentals, enought to be able to pass it to the WCF side so that the WCF side app can validate that it is a good user.  I want this so i can enable single sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write the WCF service as you would
2. use `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in your web.config
3. untick *Enable Anonymous Access* in the IIS Manager.
4. Call Thread.CurrentPrinciple.Identity.Name to verify his/her name

Comment: That will work - IF and ONLY IF the client and the server are on the same network, e.g. member of the same AD domain. Works great for company-internal Intranet scenario, not so much for internet.